# scroll to next and previous tab from tabbed box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've build a tab Container with multiple Tabs and corresponding content, which is only visible if the corresponding Tab is clicked. This works great so far, but I have tried to add two buttons which will navigate to the next and previous tab and I don't know how to achieve this.

You'll find below what I've done so far. I think it's no so good JS code, maybe someone can give me also some hint's to improve it.

Thanks in advance for your help

```js
      $(document).ready(function(){

        // hide all contents accept from the first div
        $('.tabContent div:not(:first)').toggle();

        // hide the previous button
        $('.previous').hide();

        $('.tabs li').click(function () {

            if($(this).is(':last-child')){
              $('.next').hide();
            }else{
              $('.next').show();
            }

            if($(this).is(':first-child')){
              $('.previous').hide();
            }else{
              $('.previous').show();
            }

            var position = $(this).position();
            var corresponding = $(this).data("id");

            // scroll to clicked tab with a little gap left to show previous tabs
            scroll = $('.tabs').scrollLeft();
            $('.tabs').animate({'scrollLeft': scroll+position.left-30},200);

            // hide all content divs
            $('.tabContent div').hide();

            // show content of corresponding tab
            $('div.' + corresponding).toggle();

            // remove active class from currently not active tabs
            $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');

            // add active class to clicked tab
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });


      });
```

```css
      body{
        background-color: gray;
      }

      *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .contentWrapper{
        width: 350px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
      }

      .tabsWrapper{
        width: 100%;
        height: 24px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }

      .tabs{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: -25px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      .tabs li{
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #ccc;
        padding: 3px 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .tabs li.active{
        background-color: white;
      }

      .next, .previous{
        position: absolute;
        padding: 2px 4px;
        top: 0;
        background-color: white;
      }

      .next{
        right: -25px;
      }

      .previous{
        left: -25px;
      }

      .tabContent{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 15px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentWrapper">
      <div class="tabsWrapper">
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li data-id="contentOne" class="active">CSS</li>
          <li data-id="contentTwo">HTML, HTML, HTML</li>
          <li data-id="contentThree">JS and jQuery</li>
          <li data-id="contentFour">one more tab</li>
          <li data-id="contentFive">another tab</li>
          <li data-id="contentSix">the last tab</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a class="next">></a>
      <a class="previous"><</a>
      <div class="tabContent">
        <div class="contentOne">
          <p>this is the CSS tab Content</p>
          <a href="">next</a>
        </div>
        <div class="contentTwo">
          <p>this is the HTML tab Content<br><br>1</p>
          <a href="">next</a>
        </div>
        <div class="contentThree">
          <p>this is the JS tab Content</p>
          <a href="">next</a>
        </div>
        <div class="contentFour">
          <p>this is the sample Content</p>
          <a href="">next</a>
        </div>
        <div class="contentFive">
          <p>this is more sample Content</p>
          <a href="">next</a>
        </div>
        <div class="contentSix">
          <p>this is more than more sample Content</p>
          <a href="">next</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use trigger('click') to programmatically click the tab you want. This way all the code written for tab change will automatically get executed. For example see the following code:

```
$('div a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li.active').next('li').trigger('click');
});
```

See [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/7L6guk9g/1/)